# MSI GE60 Apache 75 °C on browsing

Tags: laptop, cooling, overheating

I am having some trouble with keeping my laptop cool. It's a MSI GE60 Apache 2QD. It used to run kind of hot while playing high-end games (80-90°C) but recently it's been heating up until 80°C while simply browsing or doing very lightweight tasks. The CPU is not heavily loaded while doing these tasks either (fluctuating around 20%).
I do carry the laptop to university each day (backup and bicycle). Could that be the cause?

My best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a fan failure. It could also be an accumulation of dust. You can use a can of compressed air to gently blow dust out of the vents.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow. Thank you for the tip!